# Play audio in Safari after automatically reloading the page

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, safari, mobile-safari

I have a non-ajax webpage, that reloads periodically. From time to time the webpage changes it's content after the reload, e.g. updates on specific numbers. I know that it needs user interaction to play an audio like `new Audio("notify.mp3").play()`. So lets assume a user clicks somewhere on the page on the first load. It seems like a user would have to click on the webpage again after a reload to hear the sound. This is different in Chrome, where you just have to click once and even after a `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="50">` audio can be played again.
It this possible with Safari, too? (refresh is required, Ajax not an option).

Thanks